# Doctrine optional OneToOne entity deletion

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entities, a `Flight` and a `Booking`.

They are configured in a bi-directional one-to-one relationship, with the `Flight` underlying table holding the foreign key to the `Booking` underlying table.

The idea is that a `Flight` instance must be linked to a `Booking`, but a `Booking` can exist without a `Flight`.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Flight{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Booking", inversedBy="flight")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bookingID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
     */
    private Booking $booking;

    /// Rest of code removed for readability

}
```

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Booking{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Flight", mappedBy="booking")
     */
    private ?Flight $flight;
    
    /// Rest of code removed for readability
}
```

I do not want to use cascading operations since a `Flight` can be removed without the `Booking` being removed (this is an extension of the idea stated above).

An issue arises when I try to delete both the `Flight` and the `Booking`.

Picture the following code:

```php
// $flight holds a reference to $booking, as per the code above
$em->remove($flight);
$em->remove($booking);
$em->flush();
```

It would result in the following queries (logged by Doctrine)

```
START TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM flights WHERE ID = ?
INSERT INTO flights (redacted) VALUES (redacted)
DELETE FROM bookings WHERE ID = ?
ROLLBACK
```

Which I simply cannot understand.

If I remove the `Booking` directly through the underlying PDO Handle, it works perfectly, which means that is has to be a mapping issue, but I cannot see where I did something wrong. It's been driving me crazy for hours.